# Managing Unsubscribes,hard bounces

Tags: marketing-cloud, community, deliverability

I have **access only to email studio** and i want to suppress hard bounces and unsubscribes. So is there any automated way to do it or do I have to export them manually and then import them into suppression list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard bounces and unsubscribes are automatically suppressed as per these documents describing the processes:
[Bounces](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_bounce_mail_management.htm&type=5) - this one has a really good diagram explaining the process of marking a subscriber as **Undeliverable**, refraining from more emails being sent to that email address:

[image]

Also, [unsubscribes](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_unsubscribes.htm&type=5) is handled automatically, and should a subscriber use e.g. list-unsubscribe header method of opting out, the status on all subscribers list for that subscriber changes to **Unsubscribed**

If you indeed by writing *suppress* unsubscribes and hard bounces, mean *ignoring* them, you will need access to Automation Studio and process the data based on your data views - updating All Subscribers with this automation.

Comment: thanks, Lukas! But before making it undeliverable I think I send it for two more times and then make the status as undeliverable. I want to supress them after the first time only. I have to do that manually only as i don't have access to automation studio

Comment: OK, in that case - you can't do it in Email Studio alone, since you will need to maintain a suppression list in Automation Studio.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do it automatically with access to Email Studio only.

To be able to automate it, you would need access to Automation Studio: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_automation_studio.htm&type=5

You could then write an SQL query to regularly query the Bounce (https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_bounce.htm&type=5) and Unsubscribe (https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_unsubscribe.htm&type=5) Data Views and populate subscribers who are present in those tables to your Suppression list.

Comment: Yes, codeRage I know that my only concern was to make it automated using email studio. and I think I have to do it manually only